# Find best match of two vectors with different length in R

Tags: r

From two vectors (a, b) with increasing integers and eventually different lengths, I want to extract two vectors both with length n (=5) that lead to the smallest difference when subtracting a from b.

Example

```
a<-c(25,  89, 159, 224, 292, 358)

b<-c(1, 19,  93, 155, 230, 291)
```

Subtracting the following elements leads to the smallest difference:

```
c(25-19, 89-93, 159-155, 225-230, 291-292)
```

From a, 358 is excluded

From b, 1 is excluded.

The Problem:
The length of the vectors can vary:

Examples

```
a<-c(25,  89, 159, 224, 292, 358)

b<-c(19,  93, 155, 230, 291)


a<-c(25,  89, 159, 224, 292, 358, 560)

b<-c(19,  93, 155, 230, 291)


a<-c(25,  89, 159, 224, 292, 358)

b<-c(1 , 5, 19,  93, 155, 230, 291)
```

Because I have to find this “best match” for >1000 vectors, I would like to built a function that takes as input the two vectors with different lengths and gives me as output the two vectors with length n=5 that lead to the smallest difference.

Answer (score 2):

This works by brute force.  The columns of `combn.a` and `combn.b` are the combinations of 5 elements from `a` and `b`.  Each row of the two column data frame `g` is a pair of  column numbers of `combn.a` and `combn.b` respectiively.  `f` evaluates the sum of absolute differences of the `a` and `b` subsets corresponding to a row `r` of `g`.  `v` is the distance values found, one per row of `g`, with `ix` being the row number in `g` having the least distance.  From `g[ix,]` we can have the column numbers of the minimizer in `comb.a` and `combn.b` and from those we determine the corresponding `a` and `b` subsets.

```
align5 <- function(a, b) {
   combn.a <- combn(a, 5)
   combn.b <- combn(b, 5)
   g <- expand.grid(a = 1:ncol(combn.a), b = 1:ncol(combn.b))
   f <- function(r) sum(abs(combn.a[, r[1]] - combn.b[, r[2]]))
   v <- apply(g, 1, f)
   ix <- which.min(v)
   rbind( combn.a[, g[ix, 1] ], combn.b[,g[ix, 2] ] )
}

# test

a <- c(25,  89, 159, 224, 292, 358)
b <- c(1, 19,  93, 155, 230, 291)
align5(a, b)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,]   25   89  159  224  292
## [2,]   19   93  155  230  291
```